# UEFI not seeing SSD

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, mbr

After installing Ubuntu alongside windows 10 (windows 10 on one SSD, Ubuntu on the other SSD), I modified the MBR via my Windows following instructions online, I cannot remember why I was modifying my MBR or exactly what I did. I remember doing it from within windows via ms-dos. It was a fatal error. Now I can only boot to my UEFI and only one of my SSDs show up. When I try to boot to it, I am greeted with:

```
Non-system disk or disk error
Replace and press any key when ready

Reboot and Select proper Boot device or
Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key.
```

I can successfully boot to a windows recovery CD and I've tried the automatic repair option to no avail.

The ASUS EZ FLash 2 Utility strangely does not display my SSD as an option to format otherwise I would have done that. Contradictorily it shows up as a boot option though.

Any help would be appreciated I'm really at a loss.

Comment: I would google ... ubuntu repair mbr  ... which gives  ... https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows   ... see  https://www.google.com/search?q=ubuntu+repair+mbr&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab

Comment: I can't even boot ubuntu from usb

Comment: try this ... while booting from USB tap shift key and/or ESC keys to trigger the BIOS menu where you choose to boot from USB ... to quote `Make sure you mark a partition as active/boot as some stupid biosen refuse to load an MBR otherwise` from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/180917/unbootable-usb-stick-non-system-disk-or-disk-error

Comment: I turned off Fast Boot and used a UEFI only version of ubuntu (you simply copy the .iso files to a fat32 formatted USB). I was successfully able to install ubuntu on one of my SSDs. I'll update if/when I can fix the other which has windows 10 installed on it but is currently not showing up as an available HD

Comment: Ok I followed the answer to this question: [link](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-3288911/ssd-suddenly-auto-booting-boot-bios.html)

Now I can see my SSD in BIOS. I'm currently using windows recovery CD to get into command prompt and use diskpart. I cannot repair the drive because it has no volumes according to diskpart. I'll update when I get further.